# How the rbinom function in R works if it is in the middle of for loop?

Tags: r

I don't have enough understanding in r and want to solve my curiosity.

I read the explanation that

"rbinom function generates random deviates",

and found that even under the same seed, repetition of rbinom makes different results.

```
rbinom(1, size=10, prob=0.2)
```

But I also found that if I make "for loop" and activate rbinom in that loop, it generates the same results under the repetition.

The code I used is

```
> A=rep(0,10)
> for (i in 1:10)
+ {set.seed(i)
+ x=rbinom(1, size=10, prob=0.2)
+ A[i] = x/n}
> A
```

What is the difference between activating rbinom solely and activating rbinom in loop?

Thank you..

Comment: There is no difference. If you `set.seed(1)` before every `rbinom` call, you will get the same result every time. The difference is, in your loop you are changing the seed each iteration, first `set.seed(1)`, then `set.seed(2)` etc. If you put `set.seed(1)` *before* the loop, your loop output will be the same as repeated `rbinom` calls outside of a loop (also after `set.seed(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference isn't the loop, the difference is the call to

```
set.seed(i)
```

`set.seed` uses its argument to prime the pseudo-random number generator. If you pass it the same seed, then functions that use the internal random number generator will produce the same output.